# What is the total amount of exp needed to go from level 1 to 70 (71) in Modern Warfare 2?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2

trying to gauge how much experience I have left to go to get to 71.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This website](http://www.mlwgames.com/mw2exp/) appears to have a calculator that allows you to determine the amount of experience needed from one level to another.

Comment: sweet thanks. this is better than what I was looking for =)

Comment: flagged as not an answer because if link rot occurs, what is left is no answer - "There is a website that has a calculator that allows you to determine the amount of experience needed from one level to another." - very great, but that doesn't answer the question.

Comment: and that's exactly what happened, or my browser sucks.